# How do i edit the elements from a vutify data table footer?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

Currently in my data table i have the following default footer:
[image]

I want to be able to edit the 'Rows per page' text and the 'of' text in the footer.
How do i do that? The only thing i find in the official documentation is also the change the appearance of the footer, such as changing the arrow icons or positioning but nothing about this specific situation.
[Official documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/pt-BR/components/data-tables/)

Here is an example of a basic data table:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="data"
  :items-per-page="5"
  :search="search"
  class="elevation-1"
> </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those props are customizable via `v-data-footer` options. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/AlgeoMA/pen/zYGmEpV?editors=1010. You can find it in the docs by switching the "component" to v-data-footer at the "api" section near the top (it's a drop-down in the header).

See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization/#create-a-translation for information on custom translations.

Comment: i see you used " pageText: 'bar'" to change the text but the page numbers are not there. is there any way to add them back with the edited page text?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man If it's just text changes, see the translations link I added.